# Does setting a 'Reply-To' header mean a reply won't be sent to the 'From' address?

Tags: email, email-client

I'm sending an email programmatically upon a user's request, and I set the 'Reply-To' header to be different than the 'From' address.  Many times a reply to this email will be sent to the 'From' address.  My research here, [RFC 4021](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.4), only suggests that a reply is sent to the 'Reply-To' address.  A mention here, [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-4.4.4), doesn't seem to apply to me because I'm not automatically generating any lists for replies.  My testing in gmail has only sent replies to the 'Reply-To' address.

I get the feeling this may be email client specific because it doesn't happen in my testing, but the product owner still gets email replies to the address used as the 'From' address.

Does anyone have any experience with experience with this?

Thanks.

P.S. - I'm using Django to send the emails which are plain text, no html.

Comment: reply-to is a suggestion. most mail clients will probably honor it, but nothing says they HAVE to,

Comment: So mail clients can do what they want with headers.  Some can use the Reply-To, some can ignore it using only the From, and some could use actually use both.  Is that correct?

Comment: yah, and nothing says someone can't manually edit the TO: address while they're composing the reply. it's email - anything goes.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help.  If you want add your comment as an answer I will accept it.